# Will LibreOffice be more "Visually user friendly"?

Tags: libreoffice

I like Libreoffice. It's simple and we can done the work as we should. 
But, it's my opinion that it isn't "visually user friendly"... I've seen some interesting mockups very cool indeed. 
However, as i'm use it sometimes all day, maybe Libreoffice team should takee care some other important aspects like design. It's important though, at the moment Libreoffice it's similar than office 98 :D in terms of design and we are in XXIst century. Have you seen Apple's Keynote for instance? It's simple, beautifull and visually friendly!

Let's think about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of week are released LibreOffice 3.4, today I was looking on their website the [release notes](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/release-notes/) and [new features](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/3-4-new-features-and-fixes/), I found a couple of surprises, the first is that it has finally integrated the rendering engine of the sources, and the second is that it achieved a better integration with GTK +, which results in two features that will undoubtedly greatly enhance visual suite.

> Improve gtk+ theme integration, making
>   LibreOffice look more native. Fix menu
>   separators, Alt key issues, Toggle
>   buttons, and many widget rendering
>   details.

Answer (score 3):

You should give the TDF people time. They are just in the process of reviewing and cleaning the codebase ([you can easily help, btw!](http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Easy_Hacks)), and cosmetic and/or UI changes are bound to come afterwards.
I'm pretty confident that, yes, it will be more userfriendly in the future.

Comment: You mean TDF people.

Comment: yeah, right... somewhere, one "open" too many slipped into it :-P nicely spotted!